# Is it possible to execute an Allrun script from python

Tags: python, linux, openfoam

Here is an example of Allrun script which I usually run in Linux (ubuntu) to run OpenFOAM tutorial case. https://www.dropbox.com/s/cewhynmxapfqp2g/Allrun?dl=0

But regardless of what is inside the Allrun file, is it possible to execute it from python script?

in other words, is it possible to temporarily switch into a terminal environment within python script, so I can write code just the way I write it in terminal?

Thank you

Comment: Do you know about the `os.system(...)` command? In between the braces, you would put `bash Allrun` ( if they are in the same work directory as the python script).

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. Although I found a way (down in my reply) but a shortcut would be interesting too

Comment: `os.system` has its limitations though. the `subprocess` module surely will be more versatile in your context.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer! [here](http://www.tfd.chalmers.se/%7Ehani/kurser/OS_CFD_2010/erwinAdiHartono/erwinAdiHartonoReport.pdf)

> cmd='**./Allrun**'
> pipefile = open('output', 'w')\
> retcode = call(cmd,shell=True,stdout=pipefile)
> pipefile.close()
> os.remove('output')\

my understanding is that **./Allrun** can be replaced by any other code the way we write it in terminal, right?

Comment: `call` needs to be imported from `subprocess` module.
Regarding your question, yes `cmd` could be replaced with any shell command, since you are setting `shell=True`. If you don't need the output from the `cmd` you might can skip piping it into a file. If you expect only a short output, you might also checkout the doc for `subprocess.check_output`